# How to find out JOOQ record contains some value

Tags: record, jooq

Is there a better way to find out that org.jooq.Record contains some value than this one(f.e. in RecordMapper):

```
if (record.field(SOMETABLE.SOMECOLUMN.getName()) != null)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have do that `getName()` call, you can also just write:

```
if (record.field(SOMETABLE.SOMECOLUMN) != null)
```

Other than that, yes, that's the only way.